# Is there a way to group parameters of the same type to make the code neat?

Tags: c#

Say I have this method:

```
public void UpdateEmployee ( String empFirst, String empLast, String empAddress, 
String empType, String empPhoneNo, String empSalary, DateTime? dob, String empDepartment)
```

Is there a way not to repeat the type String all the time in the params?

Thanks

Comment: errrr, make a class called Employee and pass that to your function

Comment: How about an Employee class which stores all the employee related data?  Then, an `Update` method of that class could perform the update with no params at all because it already has access to them.  Ahhhh, OOP.

Comment: You should listen to @KeithNicholas. But if you don't, you could do (DateTime? dob, params string[] employeeValues) (and then trust your callers to supply values in the correct order, and they won't). But you shouldn't do that, because you should really listen to Keith.

Comment: Listen to Keith, that is, unless this is just an example and really the arguments do not meet the requirements for a class. If so, add a different set of details explaining why you do not want to use a class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way to do exactly what you want (That I know of) in C# but you can try records:

```
public record Employee(string First, string Last, string Address, string Type);
```

That way you can write your code like this:

```
public void UpdateEmployee(Employee emp)
{
}
```

And allows you to re-use it!

There's also a way to create alias, but it's not recommended:

```
using s = System.String;
```

This way you can write your code like this:

```
public void UpdateEmployee(s empFirst, s empLast, s empAddress,
        s empType, s empPhoneNo, s empSalary, DateTime? dob, s empDepartment)
{
}
```

Again, not recommended but good to know.

Comment: Yeah... you should move the Records option to the top of the answer, and the using renaming... to out of your answer.... humble opinion